# server GC settings in app.config dont get reflected

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

I created a simple .net 456 Console application.
In the app.config , I added

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And in 1 of the .cs file , I tried to read the settings value

```
        Console.Write($"Current Server GC mode : {System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC}");
```

The issue is : The Current Server GC mode always shows true, even though I set to false

Updated: I have even tried with command set complus_gcserver=0. 
I always get value to true

Comment: Why do you say your app is a console application but you use the [tag:asp.net] tag? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in Web.config instead of app.config